# laravel : whereHas query for getting three tables data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Define a simple query for getting three tables data

table `users`,
table `user_details`,
table `user_device_datas`

On my `LoginController` define a function to get data from `UserDetails` model .

```
 $userInformation = UserDetails::userDetail($user->id);
```

on `User` model define a relationship

```
public function UserDeviceData() {
    return $this->hasMany(UserDeviceData::class);
}

public function UserDetails()
{
   return $this->hasOne(UserDetails::class);
}
```

On `UserDetails` model my query for getting data look like

```
 public static function userDetail($id){
     $result = User::whereHas('userDetails',function($query)  use ($id) {
           $query->where('user_id',$id); 
        })->whereHas('UserDeviceData',function($query)  use ($id) {
           $query->where('user_id',$id);
        })->where('user.id', $id)
        ->with('userDetails','UserDeviceData')
        ->first();
}
```

Response i am getting :

```
 "userInfo": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": null,
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "phone": null,
    "address": null,
    "company": null,
    "description": null,
    "device_id": null,
    "system_role": "User",
    "status": "Active",
    "otp_verify_id": "253526851",
    "parent_id": 0,
    "last_login": "2018-04-23 12:03:43",
    "profile_picture": null,
    "business_card_pic": null
}
```

I am not getting my `userDetails` Data on the query.what is the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static function userDetail($id){
     $result = User::whereHas('userDetails',function($query)  use ($id) {
            $query->where('user_id',$id); 
        })->whereHas('UserDeviceData',function($query)  use ($id) {
           $query->where('user_id',$id);
        })->where('users.id',$id)
        ->with(['UserDetails' => function($query) use ($id){

               $query->where('user_id',$id); 

         }, 
         'UserDeviceData' => function($query) use ($id){
             $query->where('user_id',$id); 

         }
])
        ->first();
       return $result ;
}
```

You have to use `with()` to get the relations too.

Comment: what i can do if there is another filter on subquery.?

Comment: @Javed can you please provide an example?